# sql - how to get courses with module=5

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all courses which has only "module=5", any different course. As you can see below I have 4 courses, such as, course 2, 3, 4, 5. But just two of them has only "module=5", e.g. course 2, 5.

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | course | module |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      2 |      5 |
|  2 |      3 |      5 |
|  3 |      3 |     11 |
|  4 |      4 |      5 |
|  5 |      4 |      3 |
|  6 |      5 |      5 |
|  7 |      4 |      6 |
|  8 |      4 |      5 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I've tryed do two queries, in the first I return all courses which has module=5 and in the second I return all courses which has module!=5, then I save in 2 files and execute the unix command diff to see the difference between both files.

1. save in a file all courses which has module=5:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT fullname 
   FROM            mdl_course 
   LEFT JOIN       mdl_course_modules 
   ON              mdl_course.id=mdl_course_modules.course 
   WHERE           mdl_course_modules.module=5 
   into            outfile '/tmp/forum';
   ```
2. save in file all courses which has module!=5:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT fullname 
   FROM            mdl_course 
   LEFT JOIN       mdl_course_modules 
   ON              mdl_course.id=mdl_course_modules.course 
   WHERE           mdl_course_modules.module!=5 
   into            outfile '/tmp/plus_forum';
   ```
3. Then, execute the difference:

   ```
   $ diff forum plus_forum
   ```

But I'd like to return all courses which has only module=5 in only one query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it simple let just solve the `mdl_course_modules`

```
  SELECT course
  FROM mdl_course_modules
  GROUP BY course
  HAVING SUM(module <> 5) = 0
     AND SUM(module =  5) = 1  -- or >= 1
```

Comment: I think your second comparison needs to be `=1` or at least `>=1` (assuming course / module combinations are unique)

Comment: @jpw Yes, Always forget that in mySql

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the exists predicate with a correlated subquery.

```
select * 
from mdl_course_modules t
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from mdl_course_modules 
  where t.course = course -- reference the outer table
  and module <> 5 -- and find rows that have any other module than 5
)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25a34b/2)

Since it's not completely clear what data is in what table you'll have to adjust the table and column names to suit your setup, but the concept should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `not in` subquery to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fullname 
FROM            mdl_course 
LEFT JOIN       mdl_course_modules 
ON              mdl_course.id=mdl_course_modules.course 
WHERE           mdl_course_modules.module=5
AND course.id not in (SELECT course
                      FROM   mdl_course_modules 
                      WHERE  module <> 5)
```